# Conflict when using jQuery and prototype, already resolved with jQuery.noConflict() but

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, jquery

I'm using a combination of jQuery, jQuery mobile, prototype and photoswipe.
I'm aware that there are conflicts between jQuery and prototype due to the usage of the `$` shortcut. So I did a `jQuery.noConflict()` . Now in my Firebug Console, it doesn't report any more errors. However when I go to the Firebug DOM tag, i see:
[image]
and when I check line 4725, it's `var $continue = new Error('"throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead');`. Which was the error I got before I used `jQuery.noConflict()`. Should I be concerned?

Here are some code snippets from my HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsandcss/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsandcss/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsandcss/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsandcss/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsandcss/code.photoswipe.jquery-2.1.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="jsandcss/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

   $j(document).ready(function(){
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try including jQuery + plugins first, calling `jQuery.noConflict()`, _then_ including prototype.

Comment: @NRohler Thanks! I don't get the error anymore. But I'm wondering if that error message (refer to screenshot above) is a huge concern. Is it because I loaded the libraries first then called `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand well how you saw that error, but $continue IS an error object that before prototype 1.5 (if i remember) you could use to simulate the continue keyword in a prototype iteration (using methods each, collect, ...). Now you can simply do return in the iteration function.
FYI the $break is the same, it's a predefined error like $continue that you can throw to simulate a break in a prototype iteration. This one is kept still in active prototype version, but the $continue is deprecated now.

So yeah $continue and $break are global (= owned by the window object) and ARE some errors, but not thrown yet, just instantiated.

Hope this information is useful.